# Git RPC error 22 status 400 on Heroku deploy

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm trying to do a deploy on Heroku of a Rails 4 application, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Counting objects: 357, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (325/325), done.
Writing objects: 100% (357/357), 7.58 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 357 (delta 19), reused 347 (delta 14)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

This is on a new Heroku App, so there isn't anything inside it.

I did managed to push it once, but I had an error in my Gemfile (Sqlite gem wasn't commented), but couldn't push anymore after that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your url to an ssh url

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:reponame
```

Comment: I did that, and it gives me protocol error: expected old/new/ref. I'm guessing this is because I cloned the repo using --depth=1